# Complexity of a poset

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, posets

Let $M$ be a an integer $s \times s$ matrix.
Define the complexity of $M$ as $cx(M):= \inf \{ n \geq 0 | \exists C \in \mathbb{N} , \ \forall t \in \mathbb{N} : \| M^t \| \leq C t^{n-1} \}$.
Here $\| M \|$ is some norm for matrices.

> Question 1: Is such a definition of complexity of a matrix used/defined already somewhere?

For example a matrix with $M^k=id$ has complexity 1, the matrix \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
has complexity 2 and the matrix \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 2 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
has infinite complexity.

For a finite connected poset $P$ with incidence matrix $M=(m_{i,j})$ such that $m_{i,j}=1$ if $i \leq j$ and $m_{i,j}=0$ else, define the Coxeter matrix of $P$ as $C=C_P:=-M^{-1} M^T$.
Define the complexity $cx(P)$ of $P$ as the complexity of $C_P$. For example the complexity of the Boolean lattice is 1, while the complexity of the strong Bruhat order for $S_3$ is larger than 1.

> Question 2: Is there a class of posets that shows that posets can have arbitrary complexity $ \geq 1$ or is the complexity bounded? Is the complexity of a poset related to some or bounded by some other well known invariants?

Comment: Do I get it right that the complexity of a matrix is infinite if it has an eigenvalue of absolute value $>1$, and otherwise it is something like the maximum size of Jordan blocks corresponding to eigenvalues of absolute value $1$?